# How to make an Intent activity from Fragment? (Error on Activity name)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an intent from fragment but getting an error. I see there are a lot of posts on this subject, but nothing resolves my problem. I already added **context** and **getActivity()**.

The error I am getting is on `RegistrationActivity (Unresolved reference)`. How can I reference it? (android studio hints importing RegistrationActivity to ProfileFragment, but I would say that is not a good way to do it).
Here is the code:

```
val intent = Intent(this@ProfileFragment.context, RegistrationActivity::class.java).apply {}
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you not imported RegistrationActivity in fragment class?

Comment: No, I haven't. Do I really need to? In activities, if I use an intent, I don't need to import the activity I want to go to. I thought the same applies in fragments.

Comment: yes, you should import the others classes if you are used hem in your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comments I imported RegistrationActivity and now it works. It is good to remember that Fragments don't behave like Activities - in Activity you don't have to import another Activity, and in Fragments you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a parent activity object inside your fragment.

```
val intent = Intent (getActivity(), RegistrationActivity::class.java)
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

**or maybe something like**

```
activity?.let{
   val intent = Intent (it, RegistrationActivity::class.java)
   it.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but still getting the same error. I guess the question is weather I need to import RegistrationActivity or not. If I use intent from other activities I don't need to, but maybe fragment need to import it.

Comment: Yes fragment need to import activity.